# Unit Testing in Production Folder and Source Folder

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit5

I have created an installer for my java project. Using the installer, the user can install the software specifying where the program should be installed, where the program data folder should be located, so on and so forth. After the program is installed, like any other windows software he can open it and start using. The project basically makes some processing on files, and then writes those files to the program data folder something like C:\Program Data\MyProduct\data\myoutput.png .

Now, when I want to unit test the logic of saving files into the right place, I can't use the above location which is so-called production environment. Because, a developer who works on it doesn't have to install the software to test how the program works, or if he wants to see the output of his change. Instead, what I did is that during the execution of the program, I retrieve the information of where the program is running. If the program is running on production environment it uses this production path for outputting, if it runs on eclipse, it creates some dummy folder inside the source code folder to save the output of the processing so that the developer can check the output instead of tangling with the production folder.

Accordingly, I want to write unit test for the logic of saving of a file to the right place, like how the document is processed and then successfully saved into the folder. However, I don't want to touch to production folder because a developer who checked out the source code might not have installed the program just for running unit tests. Because he runs the program on eclipse, a dummy folder will be created and he will check from there.(these created folders are removed after the unit tests automatically via the unit test code). But in this case, I'll be able to check only if the file is saved correctly inside the source code dummy folder. It basically wont detect if the production folder logic is fine.

How could I change my approach on it to check things more correctly?

Comment: why would you ever unit test in a production environment? those tests should have been used to filter out bugs before the code even made it in the testing environment.

Comment: Because there is a logic behind how to create a path for saving files and/or if the folder is created correctly. If somebody else wants to refactor it, there should be unit tests to check if the logic is still working.

Comment: I'm not speaking up against unit tests, I'm only saying it makes absolutely zero sense to execute them on a production environment.

Comment: l know thanks, thats why l ask in the question how could l change my approach to make sure that what correctly works in the development environment is assured to work also on production setup. Or maybe my logic is wrong from the get go. :)